# Opening a link in a new window in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, window

I need a little help on this. Usually I can simply go to an HTML file and add a target to a link to make it open in a new window like so.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.somewhere.com/">My Link Text</a>
```

However, when I go into my wordpress files via FTP I do not see the anchor for me to add a target to. It is referencing the link from the database but I do not have access to that just yet so how can I hard code the target=_blank to the anchor without DB access?

As you can see below the anchor is not hard coded either. Just what I have below.

Below is the code where I should be adding the target.

```
        $title = ($resource_center_home_link_text) ? ' title="' . $resource_center_home_link_text . '"' : '';

    echo do_shortcode('[prequal url="' . $resource_center_link . '"' . $title .']');
```

Any assistance on this would be great.

Thank you

Comment: I know that I could go to posts and go to the resource center link value but without the DB access there has to be a way to hard coded here right?

Comment: 3 Questions: A) Where does the prequal shortcode come from? B) Do you want to add target="_blank" only to one link, or to many links? C) Have you tried Appearance > Edit Theme to modify a page or an element's content rather than modifying the function of a shortcode?

Comment: A) I believe it is coming from the Database through $resource_center_link and B) I only want to add target blank to just one link. However, I believe the same link may be across the site a few times. For now, the home page link will be fine. C) Yes I did go to Appearance > Edit Theme to modify a page or an element but it did not give me the option to modify the element I want to add target to.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the prequal shortcode, but see a jQuery solution. Would you be able to add a few lines of jQuery to the header rather than modify this line of code?

Comment: It's ok, I was able to find a solution for it, It was in a function template of some sort if I remember correctly. I appreciate your help.